# How do I connect 2 strings in a android project?

Tags: android

I've just learn about Android.
I have 2 strings.

```
String a = "Android";
String b = "Programming";
```

I want to have a string: `"Android Programming"`.How to do? Any suggestions ?

Comment: String c = "Android Programming"; I don't think this is what you want, but you should really clear up your question.

Answer (score 5):

1. Simple

   String c = a+" "+b;
2. StringBuilder

   String c = new StringBuilder().append(a).append(' ').append(b).toString();
3. String format

   String c = String.format("%s %s", a, b);
4. Use TextUtitls, (String[] or List)

   String c = TextUtils.join(" ", new String[]{ a, b });

Answer (score 1):

```
String c = a + " " + b;
```

Just as simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

In Java `String` concatenation can be achieved by using the `+` operator.

```
 String a = "Android"; 
 String b = "Programming";
 String c = a + " " + b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate Strings using the `+` operator:

```
String a = "Android";
String b = "Programming";

System.out.println(a  + " "+ b);

Output: Android Programming
```

Comment: If it is helpful to you, then vote up and accept this.